# Is there a term for words that are mistakenly interchanged?

Tags: synonyms, terminology

There are many words that are often used in place of other words, that are not actually synonymous.

**Examples:**

- Disinterested & Uninterested
- Ask(ed) & Axe(d)
- Literally & Figuratively*

Sometimes this is because the words are similar, sometimes it's born out of hyperbole or irony (eg good & bad), sometimes their are totally obscure reasons this happens.  Regardless, it is common enough that I would expect it to have a term.  Unfortunately trying to google for such a term, because of the way the keywords are used, returns Interminable** results with nothing pertinent within a reasonable depth.

For the record, if an appropriate term does not already exist, I'd like to coin the term **pseudosynonym**.

<sub>*yes, I know technically this is resolved by adding the informal definition to the dictionary.</sub>

<sub>**yes, I see what I did there, no it was not intentional.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These words can be considered [false cognates](http://www.alphadictionary.com/articles/confused_words_english.html):

> They are called false cognates because they sound or are written so similarly that they are often confused.

That page even lists disinterested/uninterested and literally/figuratively.

---

(Note that while the term typically refers to two words in different languages, it is also used with two words within the same language.)

Comment: This is perfect!  I was even considering adding the foreign language concept to my example, but thought it was already complicated enough.  Thank you!